# terraform azurerm - cannot destroy public ip

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

New to terraform so i'm hoping this is an easy issue. I'm creating some resources in azure and deploying a simple flask application to AKS. Creating works fine using terraform plan. I can see that azure is provisioned correctly and I can hit the flask app.

When I try to run terraform destroy I get the error - "StatusCode=400...In order to delete the public IP, disassociate/detach the Public IP address from the resource.

Main.tf

```
variable "subscription_id" {}
variable "client_id" {}
variable "client_secret" {}
variable "tenant_id" {}

provider "azurerm" {
    version         = "=1.28.0"
    tenant_id       = "${var.tenant_id}"
    subscription_id = "${var.subscription_id}"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks" {
    name        = "${var.name_prefix}"
    location    = "${var.location}"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
    name                    = "${var.name_prefix}-aks"
    kubernetes_version      = "${var.kubernetes_version}"
    location                = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks.location}"
    resource_group_name     = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks.name}"
    dns_prefix              = "AKS-${var.dns_prefix}"

    agent_pool_profile {
        name                = "${var.node_pool_name}"
        count               = "${var.node_pool_size}"
        vm_size             = "${var.node_pool_vmsize}"
        os_type             = "${var.node_pool_os}"
        os_disk_size_gb     = 30
    }

    service_principal {
        client_id           = "${var.client_id}"
        client_secret       = "${var.client_secret}"
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "${var.env_tag}"
    }
}

provider "helm" {
  install_tiller = true

  kubernetes {
    host                   = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.host}"
    client_certificate     = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_certificate)}"
    client_key             = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_key)}"
    cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
  }
}

# Create Static Public IP Address to be used by Nginx Ingress
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "nginx_ingress" {
  name                         = "nginx-ingress-public-ip"
  location                     = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.location}"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.node_resource_group}"
  allocation_method            = "Static"
  domain_name_label            = "${var.name_prefix}"
}

# Add Kubernetes Stable Helm charts repo
data "helm_repository" "stable" {
  name = "stable"
  url  = "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"
}

# Install Nginx Ingress using Helm Chart
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name       = "nginx-ingress"
  repository = "${data.helm_repository.stable.metadata.0.name}"
  chart      = "nginx-ingress"

  set {
    name  = "rbac.create"
    value = "false"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
    value = "Local"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = "${azurerm_public_ip.nginx_ingress.ip_address}"
  }
}
```

Also deploying my kubernetes stuff in this file k8s.tf

```
provider "kubernetes" {
    host                    = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.host}"
    username                = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.username}"
    password                = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.password}"
    client_certificate      = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_certificate)}"
    client_key              = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.client_key)}"
    cluster_ca_certificate  = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "flask-api-deployment" {
    metadata {
        name = "flask-api-deployment"
    }

    spec {
        replicas = 2

        selector {
            match_labels {
                component = "api"
            }
        }

        template {
            metadata {
                labels = {
                    component = "api"
                }
            }

            spec {
                container {
                    image = "xxx.azurecr.io/sampleflask:0.1.0"
                    name = "flask-api"
                    port {
                        container_port = 5000
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "api-cluster-ip-service" {
    metadata {
        name = "flask-api-cluster-ip-service"
    }

    spec {
        selector {
            component = "api"
        }

        port {
            port = 5000
            target_port = 5000
        }
    }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress" "flask-ingress-service" {
    metadata {
        name = "flask-ingress-service"
    }

    spec {
        backend {
            service_name = "flask-api-cluster-ip-service"
            service_port = 5000
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the point of provisioning ip address in the first place? it would create it on its own

Comment: it doesn't create it on its own.

Comment: it does, that's the whole point of services in kubernetes, they abstact the underlying cloud provider infrastructure

Comment: nginx ingress has some mandatory and azure specific yaml files that you must apply which then will provision the public ip and some other stuff required for the ingress controller. To do this in terraform I think you have to use helm to install nginx ingress and also provision the public ip yourself.

Comment: no, for the service to have external ip all you need to do is set it to `"type": LoadBalancer`

Comment: On Azure, if you want to use a user-specified public type loadBalancerIP, you first need to create a static type public IP address resource. This public IP address resource should be in the same resource group of the other automatically created resources of the cluster.   - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/

Comment: no, you dont need to do that on any cloud provider, read the article you linked: `On cloud providers which support external load balancers, setting the type field to LoadBalancer provisions a load balancer for your Service. The actual creation of the load balancer happens asynchronously, and information about the provisioned balancer is published in the Service’s .status.loadBalancer field.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your issue, this is a problem about the sequence of the resources. When you create the nginx ingress with the public IP, the public IP should be created first. But when you delete the public IP, it's still in use by the nginx ingress. So It causes the error.

The solution is that you can detach the public IP from the resource which uses it. Then use the destroy the resource from the Terraform. You can take a look at the [explanation in the issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1837#issuecomment-429196046).

Comment: that makes sense I think. But how do I detach prior to running terraform destroy? Is that something I have to do outside of terraform?

Comment: @MatthewTheTerrible Yes, you can detach the public IP in the Azure portal. Also, if you separate the Azure resources and the kubernetes in two terraform files. Then you can create Azure resources first and destroy the kubernetes resources first.

Comment: I can't do it through the portal. I need to do this all through one terraform command. It appears via that link you can explicitly set a "depends on" property that may help terraform know that something must be destroyed first.

Comment: Thank you for your response but what you are suggesting is manual intervention via portal which defeats the purpose of infrastructure as code in first place. If terraform knows that it wants the IP to be disassociated first why doesn't it proceed with the disassociation itself?

Answer (score 0):

The user @4c74356b41 is right, but to give more information assuming a config like this:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
  name                = "aks-e2x-nuffield-uat"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.core_rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.core_rg.location
  dns_prefix          = "aks-e2x-nuffield-uat-dns"
  kubernetes_version  = var.k8s_version
  # NOTE currently only a single node pool, default, is configured
  private_cluster_enabled = true
...
  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = "kubenet"
    load_balancer_sku  = "standard"
    service_cidr       = var.k8s_service_subnet
    pod_cidr           = var.k8s_pod_subnet
    docker_bridge_cidr = "172.17.0.1/16"
    dns_service_ip     = "40.0.8.10" # within the service subnet
  }
}
```

Where the `load_balancer_sku` is set to standard, you can access the public IP to be used elsewhere like this:

```
data "azurerm_public_ip" "k8s_load_balancer_ip" {
  name = reverse(split("/", tolist(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.network_profile.0.load_balancer_profile.0.effective_outbound_ips)[0]))[0]
  resource_group_name = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.node_resource_group
}

output "ingress_public_ip" {
  # value = azurerm_public_ip.ingress.ip_address
  value = data.azurerm_public_ip.k8s_load_balancer_ip.ip_address
}
```